# Why don't my other buttons affect the video?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have tried to add two more buttons to the example code I have seen, to practice, however after trying several things I don't understand why my two new buttons don't work and don't seem to respond when pressed.
Those two buttons are the forward and stop button, which should increase the speed and reset the video respectively.

HTML

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <img src="images/logo.png" width="200" height="200">
        <a href="index.html"> Inicio</a>
        <a href="proyectos.html"> Proyectos</a>
        <a href="sobre_mi.html"> Sobre mi</a>
        <a href="contacto.html"> Contacto</a>
    </nav>
   
    <main>
        
        
        
        <div class="video-player">
            <video
              src="Planeta.mp4"
              class="video"
            ></video>
      
            <div class="player-controls">
              <div class="video-progress">
                <div class="video-progress-filled"></div>
              </div>
      
              <button class="play-button" title="Play">►</button>
              <button class="forward" title="Forward">►►</button>
              <button class="stop" title="Stop">«</button>

      
              <input
                type="range"
                class="volume"
                min="0"
                max="1"
                step="0.01"
                value="1"
              />
      
              <div class="time">
                <span class="current">0:00</span> / <span class="duration">0:00</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <script src="video.js"></script>
        
        
        
    
        
    <footer>Copyright &copy; 2021</footer>
</body>
```

VIDEO.JS

```
    const videoPlayer = document.querySelector('.video-player')
    const video = videoPlayer.querySelector('.video')
    const playButton = videoPlayer.querySelector('.play-button')
    const forwardButton = videoPlayer.querySelector('.forward')
    const stopButton = videoPlayer.querySelector('.stop')
    const volume = videoPlayer.querySelector('.volume')
    const currentTimeElement = videoPlayer.querySelector('.current')
    const durationTimeElement = videoPlayer.querySelector('.duration')
    const progress = videoPlayer.querySelector('.video-progress')
    const progressBar = videoPlayer.querySelector('.video-progress-filled')
    
    
    //Play and Pause button
    playButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      if(video.paused){
        video.play()
        e.target.textContent = '❚ ❚'
      } else {
        video.pause()
        e.target.textContent = '►'
      }
      
    })
    function forwardButton(){
      video.playbackRate=+2
    }
    function stopButton(){
      video.currentTime = 0
      video.playbackRate = 1 
    }
    forwardButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => { 
      video.playbackRate=+2
      e.target.textContent = '►'
    })
    stopButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      video.currentTime = 0
      video.playbackRate = 1 
    
    })
    //volume
    volume.addEventListener('mousemove', (e)=> {
      video.volume = e.target.value
    })
    
    //current time and duration
    const currentTime = () => {
      let currentMinutes = Math.floor(video.currentTime / 60)
      let currentSeconds = Math.floor(video.currentTime - currentMinutes * 60)
      let durationMinutes = Math.floor(video.duration / 60)
      let durationSeconds = Math.floor(video.duration - durationMinutes * 60)
    
      currentTimeElement.innerHTML = `${currentMinutes}:${currentSeconds < 10 ? '0'+currentSeconds : currentSeconds}`
      durationTimeElement.innerHTML = `${durationMinutes}:${durationSeconds}`
    }
    
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', currentTime)
    
    
    //Progress bar
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', () =>{
      const percentage = (video.currentTime / video.duration) * 100
      progressBar.style.width = `${percentage}%`
    })
    
    //change progress bar on click
    progress.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
      const progressTime = (e.offsetX / progress.offsetWidth) * video.duration
      video.currentTime = progressTime
    })
```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors. Try choosing variables that don’t conflict with each other. `stopButton` can’t both be a function and a button; same for `forwardButton`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have a variable for each button (`forwardButton` and `stopButton`) and **you also have functions of the same name**, which overrides the reference to the buttons (and they will not work).

Remove the `forwardButton` and `stopButton` functions as the event handler does the same thing and it should work just fine.

Or try a logic like below (use unique names for functions and variables)

```
//const forwardButton = videoPlayer.querySelector('.forward')
const btn_forward = videoPlayer.querySelector('.forward');

btn_forward.addEventListener('click', (e) => {  do_forwardButton(); });

function do_forwardButton( )
{
    //# a test popup to confirm if the function works
    alert( "I was clicked: btn_forward" );
    
    video.playbackRate += 2;
    btn_forward.textContent = '►';
}
```